# what's better? deleting file and using git add -u or git rm

Tags: git, github, repository

I know there are two approaches to delete files from git repo. One is delete file manually and then use `git add -u` to stage those files. Other is using `git rm` command. When to use which?

Comment: those are exactly the same (take a look at the man pages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the files are still in the working tree, I prefer [`git rm`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm) which, by default, will remove the file I want both from the index and the working tree.

But if the files are already removed from the index by an external operation, then [`git add -u`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) is a more practical choice.

Note that both commands supports the `-n` or `--dry-run` option: always useful to check what those command would do *before* actually removing anything from the index.

Answer (score 2):

The two methods are equivalent as far as git is concerned. Just use the one that fits *your* workflow better.